# Get data from Mysql database in real time Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, sockets, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app which users can send a notification to another one.

Moreover, I'm using php scripts to retrieve and sent data to my Mysql database.

Using Volley, a user can inserts a new row into table 'Notifications', but I don't know how to listen that insert from the app.

I mean, now the user who sent the notification in the database should call the method *getNotificationsFromDB()* to get notifications and see them on a RecyclerView (like Facebook Notifications). There's no other way. And only can know about Notifications if he is running the app.

For example, a Notification could be like this: 'John has sent you a notification'.

Also, this thread runs on the Notifications Fragment...

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getNotificacionsFromDB();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
                run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

But it should consume a lot of resources from device. A friend told me it could be with Triggers running on 'the runtime' of android. But actually I didn't understand him.

How can I listen updates from my MySql DB to create a Push Notification? 
Is there a way using Services like IntentService? or how SocialApps like Facebook or twitter manage the database updates?
Is GCM a good option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Bruno said it is required to have a server in order for your app to receive GCM messages and vice versa. The [docs have an example using Java Smack library](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/ccs.html). But you don't necessarily have to use Java. Since the upstream message you send to the server from the Android devices **MUST** be xmpp protocol if you decide to use php then you might wanna look into [xampp server](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which supports xmpp protocol. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I dit it :D thank you, but now I don't know if it is the best practice sending data using volley to a rest api/php script on my host and this script send data to gcm server and the app listen the notifications and show it. By the way, GCM is the best!

Comment: I don't see why not. Please accept my answer as accepted answer if it answered your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture is quite unorthodox.  You can't have GCM messages without a server pushing those GCM messages.  Are you sure you don't want to build a server in between your device and database?  Your setup looks very vulnerable to attacks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if i use GCM, i must create a php script which I insert on DB and then i call to GCM server and it answer to the device whom user i sent the notification is loged in? I don't know how to start